# Forward ethernet internet connection to computer via second network card

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have one machine (machine A) with two network cards, eth0 is connected via ethernet to the office wall as an internet connection. I have a [secondary USB network card](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ethernet-Adapter-Macbook-Chromebook-Windows/dp/B00MYT481C/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1488897538&sr=8-2-spons&keywords=usb%20ethernet%20adapter&psc=1) which is connected via ethernet to a second machine (machine B). I would like to gain internet access on the second machine via this connection.

I've tried googling around and have tried a few things and haven't had any success. Following [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#Ubuntu_Internet_Gateway_Method_.28iptables.29) didn't solve the problem either.

This is my network interfaces file on machine A:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Machine B is configured to have a static IP of `192.168.0.5`, netmask of `255.255.255.0` and gateway of `192.168.0.1`.
For what it's worth, I'm able to ping machine B from machine A and also machine A from machine B. I'm just unable to receive the internet connection from machine A.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your /etc/network/interfaces file, the interface eth0 is missing. It should be:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#The interface connected to internet
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#The interface connected to machine B
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You must restart networking service after making changes on that file:

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

Besides that, you should known how your system designates your network interfaces. It depends on the version of Ubuntu you are running. In 14.04 the interfaces are designated as eth0, eth1, wlan0, wlan1... and on 16.04 enp5s0, wlp1s0... You can figure out the name of your interfaces with `ip addr` command.

Finally, you should activate ip foward by uncommenting this line:

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

on the /etc/sysctl.conf file.

For applying the new configuration:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

And create iptables rules for activating nat, like the article of Help Ubuntu that you linked, shows.

Comment: Thanks, I've now got it working thanks to your help + the addition of changing the DNS severs to the address of an OpenDNS server.